# DefectInstanceDataObj is getting null all the time Using coverity 6.5 java API

Tags: java, webservice-client, coverity

First of all i am new in coverity. I am using coverity 6.5. And i'm using the java Api for getting the defetct values. I can get the total no of defects from the coverity server.
Now I want to get the the line number of the defects. I can get the other datas like CID,owner,severity, file name etc. But i couldn't get the line number.
Here is the code i am using to find the line number.

```
StreamDefectDataObj [] streamDefectsDataObj = service.getStreamDefects(cids,sDFS);
for(int j=0; j<streamDefectsDataObj.length; j++)
{                
  DefectInstanceDataObj[] defectInsDataObjs = streamDefectsDataObj[j].getDefectInstances();
  for(int k=0;k<defectInsDataObjs.length;k++)
  {
    EventDataObj[] eventDataObjs = defectInsDataObjs[k].getEvents();
    for(int l=0;l<eventDataObjs.length;l++)
    {                               
      beginline = eventDataObjs[l].getLineNumber();
    }       
  }
}
```

Here `streamDefectsDataObj` is getting perfectly. But `defectInsDataObjs` is NULL all the time. How this happens?
Please help me to find the issue.?